# ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table '....' doesn't exist in engine after upgrade mariadb

Tags: mariadb, upgrade, centos-7

I need use JSON_OBJECT builtin mariadb function, but mariadb version in server `10.0.xx`,
then we upgrade to `10.4.20-MariaDB`.

Then now mariadb version is `10.4.20-MariaDB`

But some table can't be accessed with error message:

```
select * from <tbl_name>;
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table '<db.tbl>' doesn't exist in engine
```

I was browse then found that should run `mysql_upgrade` again has some error:

```
mysql.gtid_slave_pos
Error    : Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed

mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed

mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
```

Environment:
-OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? Did you just do the package upgrade with the same datadir? If you copied selective files this could explain your errors.

Comment: @danblack I don't know how its upgrade. couse it doing by other division

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table.